# Shell script :Replace special characters by another character

Tags: bash, shell

I have file which have special character on its name and I want to replace every special character of it by a "X":

My special characters: space, ! @ ' ? & ( ) [ ] `

I tried with `sed` and `tr` but I didn't find a way to make it work, I thought about using [:alanum:] of `tr` but I don't want other characters to change.

Here is the name of my file:

```
aze !on'(@?.txt
```

the result I want is :

```
azeXXonXXXX.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

In bash, you can use `mv` with parameter substitution

```sh
#! /bin/bash
touch "aze !on'(@?.txt" "aze,!@'?&()[]\`"
for f in aze* ; do
    mv "$f" "${f//[ ,\!@?&()\[\]\'\`]/X}"
done
```

If you want to use `tr`, you can:

```sh
for f in aze* ; do
    new=$(tr ' ,!@?&()[]`'\' 'X'  <<< "$f")
    mv "$f" "$new"
done
```

Or, using a POSIX class,

```sh
    new=$(printf %s "$f" | tr -c '[:alnum:].' X)
    # or
    new=$(tr -c '[:alnum:].\n' X <<< "$f")
```

Note that the newline needs to be included with `<<<`, as it's added to the input and subsequently replaced by `X` if not included.

Same for sed:

```sh
    new=$(sed 's/[][ ,!@?&()`'\'']/X/g' <<< "$f")
```

Comment: The OP might want to consider `tr -c '[:alnum:].' X` or similar

Comment: HereString `<<< "$f")` is not POSIX

Comment: @LéaGris: The question is tagged `bash`.

Answer (score 0):

Using POSIX `IFS`. Not exactly what you asks for, since it may replace multiple forbidden chars by a single `X`.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

join ()
{
  IFS=$1
  shift
  echo "$*"
}

# Treat these as Internal Field Separators
# So they are discarded
IFS=' !@'\''?&()[]'

from_name="aze !on'(@?.txt"

# shellcheck disable=SC2086 # Explicit word splitting
to_name=$(join X $from_name)

echo mv "$from_name" "$to_name"
```